# laravel - cannt open paths.php on server

Tags: centos, laravel

this ones a weird one. For some reason, out of the blue, everytime I create a new project and upload to my server, it wont allow me to edit the paths.php file through FTP.

I accessed the server through command line earlier on today to install a bundle and noticed the paths.php file was green and has a star next to it. Does any one know what this means and is it affecting me from opening this file?

regards

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The permission of the file is 755 which mean:

```
755 = rwx r-x r-x
Owner has Read, Write and Execute
Group has Read and Execute only
Other has Read and Execute only
```

Viewing the picture, qsradmin is the owner of the file, so he is the only one who can write or edit the file.

In order to change the owner of the file, use chown command like this:

```
chown NameOfTheUser path.php
```

For more information checkout [Unix File permission](http://docs.joomla.org/How_do_UNIX_file_permissions_work?)

Comment: hmmm thats weird. Thank you. Will try changing to root. Thanks!

Comment: I am logged in as qsradmin and changed to root but still no joy.

Comment: `-rwxr-xr-x.  1 root     qsradmin  5562 Feb 20 10:13 paths.php*`

Comment: the star of the file it's because the file have 0755 permission. If you change a file to 755 with chmod and view the result, the file now is append with the star